# How to get short URL link in android using Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to share a link which would redirect a user to YouTube link if clicked on a desktop browser and redirect to the app if clicked on Android.The links are working fine but I'm getting the deep link instead of short link

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String path = uri.getPath();
```

Is there a way to get the short link in android ?

Comment: you mean you want to share short link instead of deep link ? Can you provide more information ?

Comment: I'm able to share short link but when I click on that link and start android application to parse that link using `getIntent().getData()` I get the deep link. Is there a way to get the short link too?

Comment: How do you generate short link? Share code snippet as well.

Comment: I dont generate short link from code. I use firebase console's dynamic link section.

Comment: That's not the way. You are going in wrong direction then. There is a separate REST API by Firebase to create short links. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a workaround this problem passing params in my deep link.
For e.g.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0brSA1cyzw&deeplinkparam=somevalue
```

So, the deep link in above url is

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0brSA1cyzw
```

and the param that I want to pass is appended by `&deeplinkparam=somevalue`

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this to get the link in your android app.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            var deepLink: Uri? = null
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                Log.d("LINK :: ", deepLink)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this) { e -> Log.d("Error", e) }
```

Comment: I'm getting the deep link and not the short link.

Comment: then it is sure that you can't get back the shortlink from firebase deep link.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the short link using

```
Bundle dynamicLinkBundle = pendingDynamicLinkData.zzc();                          
String shortLink = bundle1.getBundle("scionData")
    .getBundle("dynamic_link_app_open")
    .getString("dynamic_link_link_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on Kotlin

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            
            val gson = Gson()
            val json: String = Gson().toJson(pendingDynamicLinkData)
            val element: JsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement::class.java)
            val jsonObj: JsonObject = element.asJsonObject
            val dynamicLinkData = jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("dynamicLinkData")
            val shortLink = dynamicLinkData.get("dynamicLink").asString
           
        }.addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->

        }
```